# MySQL - IF/THEN statement determines INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to set up an If/Then statement that determines what is inserted into the "course" table in my database. The first INSERT INTO limits the insert to 6 rows, and the second limits it to 7.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
If @courseprogram = 'PharmTech' Then
    INSERT INTO course (fameid, course_id, enroll_status)
    SELECT @fameid fame_id, course_id, 'S' enroll_status FROM calendar
    WHERE startdate >= @startdate AND program = @courseprogram ORDER BY startdate LIMIT 6;
Elseif @fullprogram = 'Medical Assisting'
    INSERT INTO course (fameid, course_id, enroll_status)
    SELECT @fameid fame_id, course_id, 'S' enroll_status FROM calendar
    WHERE startdate >= @startdate AND program = @courseprogram ORDER BY startdate LIMIT 7;
End if
```

When I try running this, I get the following error message:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'If @courseprogram = 'PharmTech' Then  INSERT INTO
>   course (fameid, course_id, enr' at line 1

Does anyone know what might be the issue here?

Also, I've read in a couple of posts around this issue that IF/THEN statements should be avoided in MySQL all together. Could anyone explain why this is and how else to approach the problem?

Comment: The `IF` statement is a control flow construct that is only allowed in programming blocks -- stored procedures, triggers, and fucntions.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . This would be one way to do this in a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO course (fameid, course_id, enroll_status)
    (SELECT @fameid as fame_id, course_id, 'S' as enroll_status
     FROM calendar
     WHERE @courseprogram = 'PharmTech' AND
           startdate >= @startdate AND
           program = @courseprogram
     ORDER BY startdate
     LIMIT 6
    ) UNION ALL
    (SELECT @fameid as fame_id, course_id, 'S' as enroll_status
     FROM calendar
     WHERE @fullprogram = 'Medical Assisting' AND
           startdate >= @startdate AND
           program = @courseprogram
     ORDER BY startdate
     LIMIT 7
    );
```

I'm not arguing that this is *elegant*.  Merely that it solves your problem.

Note:  I am guessing that the condition `@fullprogram = 'Medical Assisting'` in the second subquery should really be `@courseprogram = 'Medical Assisting'`.